# Edit external JavaScript file after breakpoint is hit

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, debugging, ide

In the VS2010 IDE when a breakpoint (or an error) is hit, it opens a read-only [dynamic] version of the external JavaScript file I referenced. My workflow would be vastly improved if I could immediately edit this file, and refresh the browser. That is as opposed to digging up the original JS file opening it, finding the correct line and editing there.

I only know that this is possible because I was able to do this on my old work computer configuration, but for the life of me I can't duplicate it at home.

Has anyone made this work? Perhaps an extension? or maybe it has to with the way the files are referenced, or my basehref tag, or url rewriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when the base href specifies a domain other than localhost. My issue was that to enable a local environment for Facebook JS, I need my domain in the url. So I set up my host file to remap localhost.mydomain.com to localhost.

When the Visual Studio IDE encounters a file reference which is something other than localhost, it does not attempt to grab the local file since it assumes (correctly in most cases) that it is being served from another site. In these cases it loads a file as [dynamic] and readonly.

Here is the test case:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>        
        <base href="http://localhost.mydomain.com/virtual-directory/" />    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
</html>
```

Any breakpoint within test.js will result in opening a readonly dynamic file.

Answer (score 0):

how are you referencing your files? whenever a script block is written inside the html or is dynamically inserted the debugger will open the instance of the page where the code stops. If you reference the script using  tags vs should open the original script file (at least that's what it does on my machine). could you upload an example of your current structure?

Comment: I reference the script in tags pointing to the external css. But maybe the issue is that I'm doing url rewriting (via the global.asax and 404s). Perhaps that has something to do with it?

Comment: never used url rewriting... still, it would be great if you could post some code...

Comment: Thanks Nicolás. After I built the test case the answer because apparent. The project is a large Facebook integrated website with url rewriting, so the answer was obscured from me by its complexity.